# How to add a banner to default iphone theme

Tags: static-block

i've found this line in app\design\frontend\default\iphone\template\page\1column.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('homepage.banner') ?>
```

it seems adding a banner into the page, but where/how can i make this line of code useful? add  a static block? what is homepage.banner referring?

Answer (score 1):

you can find `homepage.banner` either in the banner module layout file or `page.xml` in `app\design\frontend\default\iphone\layout\`. `homepage.banner` will be the alias of the block that is used to show the banners.